# Как извлечь <p>, когда классы одинаковые?

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup

Столкнулся с проблемой при разработке парсера: `'tariff' : item.find()` должен спарсить `<div class="col col-currency-rate"><p>**12,24**</p><p>**с использованием электроплит**</p><p>**объем от 0 до 100  кВт**</p>` эту часть. Но при парсе постоянно дает **None**. Когда использую другие способы, то вообще дает город.

```
provider.append({
        'title' : item.find('div', class_ = 'col col-currency').get_text(strip = True),
        'city' : item.find('div', class_ = 'col col-currency-rate').get_text(strip = True),
        'tariff' : item.find()
    })
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col col-currency"><a target="_blank" href="http://energougol21.kz/index.php">Энергоуголь XXI</a>   </div>
                <div class="col col-headery col-currency-rate"><p>Город</p></div>
                <div class="col col-headery col-currency-rate"><p>Тариф, тенге. за 1 кВт⋅час, с НДС</p></div>
                <div class="col col-headery col-currency-rate"><p>Дата вступления в действие тарифа</p></div>
                <div class="col col-currency-rate">
                    Сарань                    </div>
                <div class="col col-currency-rate">
                    <p>12,24</p>
                    <p>с использованием электроплит</p>
                    <p>объем от 0 до 100  кВт</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-currency-rate">    01.01.2020</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

При такой структуре - только перебирать вложенные теги и брать нужные:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>> html = '<div class="row"><div class="col col-currency"><a target="_blank" href="http://energougol21.kz/index.php">Энергоуголь XXI</a>   </div><div class="col col-headery col-currency-rate"><p>Город</p></div><div class="col col-headery col-currency-rate"><p>Тариф, тенге. за 1 кВт⋅час, с НДС</p></div><div class="col col-headery col-currency-rate"><p>Дата вступления в действие тарифа</p></div><div class="col col-currency-rate">Сарань</div><div class="col col-currency-rate"><p>12,24</p><p>с использованием электроплит</p><p>объем от 0 до 100  кВт</p></div><div class="col col-currency-rate">01.01.2020</div></div>'

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> tariff = soup.find('div', class_='row').find_all('div', class_='col-currency-rate')[4].find_all('p')[0].text

>>> tariff
'12,24'
```

Т.е. если на всех страницах одинаковый уровень вложений - возьмите пятый `col-currency-rate`, найдите в нем все `p`, и выделите текст у первого их них...